# Can TinyXml load Xml from string instead of file?

Tags: tinyxml, tinyxml++

I'm using TinyXml library for my application but TiXmlDocument object just only can load Xml file. How can it load Xml from string. Could you tell me the way to do this. Thank you very much

Tu.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Instead of calling TiXmlDocument::LoadFile() you can use TiXmlDocument::Parse()

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
doc.Parse((const char*)filedata, 0, TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8);
```

Check [DotScene Loader with User Data Class](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=DotScene+Loader+with+User+Data+Class)

Comment: Thanks volody for you answer. It's useful for me.